# Error Building INET in omnet++

Tags: ubuntu, omnet++, inet

I'm working on Ubuntu and I've installed last version of simulator omnet++ 5.3. I've downloaded INET Framework 3.6.4 and after importing it on omnet++ I get an error when building it, which is:

`inet/common/geometry/common/CoordinateSystem.cc:21:10: fatal error: osgEarthUtil/ObjectLocator: No such file or directory
 #include <osgEarthUtil/ObjectLocator>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-release/src/inet/common/geometry/common/CoordinateSystem.o] Error 1
Makefile:1330: recipe for target '../out/gcc-release/src/inet/common/geometry/common/CoordinateSystem.o' failed
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/noelia/Downloads/inet/src'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Do you know why this is happening? or if it is a problem about versions? How can I include the missing file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 18.04, I've been able to build INet without errors by following [torokati44's "cherry-picking"](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues/314). His post links to [this](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/commit/fccb335dfcb01e2890e4b39a8d65610f4010d6e9) commit. Here are the steps I did:

1. Download the very latest development release of [INet](https://inet.omnetpp.org/Download.html) (i.e. inet-3.99.3);
2. If you have an INet installed in OMNeT, launch OMNeT and delete inet in the project explorer. Either check "Delete project contents on disk (cannot be undone)" OR move the inet folder elsewhere **after** deleting from the project explorer hierarchy in OMNeT;
3. Uncompress the inet downloaded from step 1) and place it at the same location as the one removed in step 2);
4. Replace the 4 files by the ones from the fccb335 commit by torokati44 (see above). I suggest you rename the files with the ".bak" extension instead of removing/replacing them, just in case;
5. In OMNeT, import the new inet (File > Import... > General > Existing Projects into Workspace). **DO NOT** copy the project into the workspace, as INet has already been moved in the workspace on step 3);
6. You should be able to build INet, and it will hopefully work.

Hope this works for you ! Cheers.

Comment: It worked! the only problem after changing the 4 files is the use of rad() and deg() in the new code. But I also solved it. Thanks